# Self sizing label

Tags: swift, label, swift2

I'm working on chat. So I stopped where I should do self-sizing labels to display text.
I tried to make my label as:

```
messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.chatScrollView.frame.size.width - 90, CGFloat.max)
messageLabel.sizeToFit()

messageLabel.frame.origin.x = (self.chatScrollView.frame.size.width - self.messageX) - messageLabel.frame.size.width
                        messageLabel.frame.origin.y = self.messageY
```

but my label didn't appear at all. If I make some exact height of my label for example 100 and comment line

```
 //messageLabel.sizeToFit()
```

so the whole label code:

```
let messageLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
messageLabel.text = self.messageArray[i]
messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.chatScrollView.frame.size.width - 90, CGFloat.max)
messageLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()

messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
messageLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
messageLabel.sizeToFit()

messageLabel.textAlignment = .Left
messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo", size: 20)
messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()


messageLabel.layer.zPosition = 20
messageLabel.frame.origin.x = (self.chatScrollView.frame.size.width - self.messageX) - messageLabel.frame.size.width
messageLabel.frame.origin.y = self.messageY
print(self.messageArray[i])
print("label origin \(messageLabel.frame.origin.x, messageLabel.frame.origin.y)")
self.chatScrollView.addSubview(messageLabel)
self.messageY += messageLabel.frame.size.height + 30

let width = self.view.frame.size.width

self.chatScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, self.messageY)
self.chatScrollView.bringSubviewToFront(messageLabel)
```

**Edit #1**

1. Label definitely has text (print statement proofs it)
2. Label origin is on the screen area (second print statement proofs it)

**Question**: How I can fix it (or how I can make my label appear and be self-sizing label)?

Comment: When you call `messageLabel.sizeToFit()` does `messageLabel` contains some text ? Perhaps the text is empty and it is resizing it to zero width.

Comment: Use **bringSubviewsToFront** method .

Comment: @NeverHopeless it contains for sure

Comment: @sourav, it doesn't change anything. It only appears when I change the height to exact number and commend line with .sizeToFit() as well

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! 
I just put my

```
messageLabel.text = self.messageArray[i]
```

right under the

```
let messageLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
```

so my label appeared!